# finding maxima of a function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I want to characterize all (countably infinite) maxima of this function $f(x) = \frac{\text{sin}^{2}(x)}{x}$. I tried the derivative approach, and it gives me the equation:
$\frac{\text{tan}(x)}{x} = 2$ (by equation $f^{'}(x) = 0$ and cancelling a $\text{sin}(x)$ term). How do I solve for $x$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try drawing functions $y=tg{x}$ and $y=2x$. Their interceptions are the solutions of that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try graphing each side of the equation  $$\tan x= 2x, \;x\neq 0$$ to visualize where the functions $(y = \tan x, \;y = 2x)$ intersect:

[image]

The roots of $f'(x) = 0$ can be numerically approximated (see, e.g., [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%20x%20=%202x)). WA lists $x=0$ as a point of intersection, but there can not be a maximum when $x = 0$ because your function is undefined there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but is there an analytic way to obtain maxima? I am trying to obtain an exact solution.

Comment: You can, at best, approximate (and get fairly precise results with numerical analysis). There is no way to isolate $x$ here.